# Why am I missing the the geometry column (geometry_columns)?

Tags: boundless-suite

Can anyone tell me what could I be doing wrong? I have installed OpenGeo and started doing the exercises. I noticed that every time I create a database through the pgAdmin, the geometry column (geometry_columns) is not created. Did I missed a step?

Comment: Can you share the output of `SELECT postgis_full_version();` for the newly created db?

Comment: "POSTGIS="2.0.1 r9979" GEOS="3.3.3-CAPI-1.7.4" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" LIBXML="2.7.6""

Comment: `geometry_columns` is a table _(or a "view")_ in this case. Expand (+) the 'public' schema in your new db, also expand 'views' - it should be a view in there.

Comment: Why it is not a table as well? Just like I have seen in the excercises...

Comment: Views are usually a table created from pre-existing tables or conditions. What's neat about pgadmin is that you can highlight that view, and see the SQL to the right on how it was created (_...or being created_).

Comment: So I can disregard this issue and continue with the exercise? It is a normal behavior or do I need to create the table with that SQL script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, your not missing the geometry column, because [geometry_columns](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#geometry_columns) is actually a table which is in the database as a view.

You can find this geometry_columns view in the `public` schema of the newly created database from the postgis template.

[Views](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createview.html) are tables that aren't usually stored on disk *(unless you use the new [materialized views](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rules-materializedviews.html) coming in 9.3)* and they can be created from existing tables or a pre set of SQL conditions. You can inspect those views with pgadmin easily by highlighting them and seeing the SQL output in the bottom right panel. It explains what was or is being used to create that view.

Views are really neat, especially when I seen a video on how dynamic they can be - I don't think tables can do this: [Dynamic Queries in PostGIS w/ QGIS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oOhbbEkl4Kg)

You don't usually need to worry about the geometry_columns view because it's a view that was created by the postgis extension when it was installed to the postgresql database. This is a table that postgis will make use of as you continue the exercise - it happens in the background automatically.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information and clarifying my doubts!

Comment: I also have this problem when I am importing an sql from a backup from postgresql 8.3 into 9.3. I had "geometry_columns" as a table in my old database and now it is a view in 9.3. I tried to import it but got an error creating the table since it already exists as a view. And I can not drop the view since it complains that POSTGIS needs it.

Comment: I have a line in my sql that inserts a post into the table. I guess you can not import a record to a view (??) This line does not work then: **INSERT INTO "geometry_columns" VALUES ('', 'public', 'darwincore2', 'punkt_geom', '2', '4326', 'MULTIPOINT');**  - How do I solve this?

Comment: @asle I find it difficult to have discussions and answer questions in comments. Did you get a chance to search the site for other answers that might help? If you don't find something, consider posting these as questions instead. They'll get the attention they deserve and lead to more answers or clarification =) For postgresql related issues, I've found it useful to browse the dba.stackexchange.com site too.